# Convert special characters from PHP variables?

Tags: php

I can print a url with the following:

```
<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>
```

What is the standard PHP way of converting special characters?

So instead of: http://time.com/3525666/ebola-psychology-fear-symptoms/

I need http%3A%2F%2Ftime.com%2F3525666%2Febola-psychology-fear-symptoms%2F

Comment: have you looked at [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) for that sort of escaping.

Other escaping functions exist for other purposes, like `htmlspecialchars` for making text output safely for HTML display.

Answer (score 1):

use his function in php , it is built in function to encode in url format

```
  urlencode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, htmlspecialchars, as mentioned above in the comment can take care of few html entities, not all of them.

Use htmlentities() instead:

$query_string = 'foo=' .urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);echo '';

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` takes care of all HTML tags, as it escapes `<` and `>`. Without those, you don't have an HTML tag.

Comment: No, it doesn't take care of every html entities, only special ones and that's what the function name implies. Please Refer http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: HTML tags and HTML entities are not the same thing.

Comment: Fine, i have editied my answer, changed to html entites now. My mistake.